# Intel HDMI monitor not recognized

Tags: arch-linux, xrandr, multi-monitor, intel, hdmi

#### The problem

I've got two graphics cards in my computer:

- Nvidia GTX 580
- Intel Graphics (onboard)

The Nvidia part is working fine: plugged in a DVI cable to my monitor and everything works perfectly. The Intel part is totally ignored. `xrandr` says it is disconnected, and even `tty` is not visible at the Intel/HDMI display.

When having `xf86-video-intel` installed, my monitor says `no signal`, if it is uninstalled, it says `1024-768 connected` with a black screen. (completely black, no `tty`)

#### Information

I am using `Arch Linux`.

After installing `xf86-video-intel` I also added to `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` the `i915` tag in the `MODULES` line:
`MODULES="i915"`

Calling `uname -r` gives me:
`3.14.25-1-lts`

Calling `lscpi -v` gives me (among other things):

```
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 0122
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

Calling `xrandr` gives me:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-I-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

#### Possible causes which are not the cause

- The cable is not the problem. It runs perfectly fine booting on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert, but as far as I know, on board graphics are *always* disabled when you add a video card. I run three monitors, and I've set up dual monitors on several machines, but I have never once got the onboard video to work at all once addon cards are inserted.  I'd love to be mistaken about that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've always got a dedicated graphics card, but prefer to run the onboard one (at Linux). This somehow seemed to work so far. The only problem is when combining them ...

Comment: Well, if you ever get an onboard to work in combination with a card, please let me know, I never have, the card always kills the onboard.  I read somewhere that this is hard coded onto motherboards or in BIOS or something, and can't be cured, but I'd love to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The BIOS is responsible for deciding whether or not the IGD is enabled when a graphics card is present. However, `nvidia` and Catalyst may not allow "rebuffering" of the graphics card output into the IGD buffer even when the IGD is enabled.

Comment: Source: I'm running `radeon` for my graphics card and have Intel graphics enabled as well, with a monitor attached to each.

Answer (score 0):

I have a integrated Intel GPU. The HDMI monitor is connected through a mini DP port to HDMI output (some reduction), the docking station should be the final solution, but I don't have one. It doesn't work at start.

My solution was

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080
```

and it works.

It's necessary to do everything through `xrandr` directly, because the GUI doesn't see the monitor, `xrandr` too, but its possible to set it direct.